# Wordpress - script to change any level of unordered list to index of content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a problem creating a wordpress code that will allow me to put only parts from the entire menu on the page. I do not want to put the menu as a regular menu more like a table of contents.

The project I'm working on is available at:
http://adepol.pl/

As you can check with the help of the menu button (between search and facebook, at the top of the page) the menu has a lot of items (unfortunately the customer does not want to consolidate the menu item).

I would like to be able to get automatically (with the help of shortcode) something like on the subpage:
http://adepol.pl/tasmy/

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

With the set elements later with css I can handle, I mean the script to extract the individual levels of the list and the sublist assigned to them.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

i had to do something similar once (if i understand correctly) and i used the menu shortcode plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-shortcode/

try it out! let me know if you need more!